# Using Vorbis and NAudio to play OGG files

Tags: c#, naudio, ogg, vorbis

I'm trying to play OGG file stream with NVorbis and NAudio, as described in the documention i'm trying to access VorbisWaveReader class, without success, here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using NVorbis;
using NAudio;

namespace Paradise
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var vorbis = new NVorbis.NAudioSupport.VorbisWaveReader(@"C:\PATH\TO\OGG\FILE.ogg"))
            using (var waveOut = new NAudio.Wave.WaveOut())
            {
            waveOut.Init(vorbis);
            waveOut.Play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
type or namespace name 'VorbisWaveReader' does not exist in the namespace 'NVorbis.NAudioSupport'
```

It looks very basic and should work, i can see in the source code that VorbisWaveReader is present in the code, can you help me go thorugh that?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you use the DLLs or the sources?

Comment: Make sure you have referenced both NVorbis.dll and NVorbis.NAudioSupport.dll in your project (and NAudio.dll, obviously).  Also, waveOut.Play() is async, so you won't actually hear anything (except maybe a pop or two) with this code.  You'll have to delay somehow before exiting the using clause.

Answer (score 3):

`NVorbis.NAudioSupport` change into `NAudio.Vorbis`

in Package-Manager Console type this:

`Install-Package NAudio.Vorbis`

Comment: Hi @Hossein Is it possible to cut the OGG audio file using NVorbis Library to the required timeslots?